# Getting response code with hvac

Tags: python, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to find a way to get the response code of an API call I make.

I am connecting to a vault server and trying to fetch usernames and passwords.
But my requirement changed and now I just want to monitor the HTTP response to my API call.

My code is :

```
#/usr/bin/python
import os
import hvac
import requests

def establishConnection(crt,key):
    client = hvac.Client(url='https://127.0.0.1:8200',
                         verify=False,
                         cert=(crt, key))
    try:
        client.auth_tls()
    except (ConnectionRefusedError, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError, hvac.exceptions.VaultDown):
        print("establishConnection() failed.")
    return client

def apiCheck(crt, key):
    client = establishConnection(crt, key)

    result = client.read('secret/prometheus')['data']['password']
    # In the above line, rather than having the value returned , I want the response code.
```

I have tried to seaxch out multiple solutions but none seem to be `hvac` specific.

I could use `requests.head` or `urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()` but then Ill have to write a whole separate piece of code for that rather than being able to reuse the `establishConnection(crt,key)` function.

Any idea how i can modify only `apiCHeck()` function to get the response code ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick gander at the hvac code, you don't have access to the underlying status and it isn't saved.  You could subclass a new hvac module and slightly modify it.  But, your question is can you just modify the single function. Although I would not do it this way, I think it answers the question:

```
result = client._get('/v1/secret/prometheus').status_code
```

Or, you could do it like this:

```
result = client._get('/v1/secret/prometheus')
result.json() # has the json return value and
result.status_code # this is the number you are looking for
```